# how to configure sms with Cakephp to send sms

Tags: php, cakephp, sms

can you suggest some php api available to send sms through cake app?

I have used

- https://central.clickatell.com/api/add servica
- http://www.panaceamobile.com/docs/PanaceaApi/PanaceaApi.html

But both are not working. even I have used

- http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/219/CakePHP_SMS_Component

but  it need sms service provider. Please suggest free service provider for testing in developer account.

Comment: There is now also https://github.com/fotografde/cakephp-sms

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->Sms->number = '5551234567'; //10 digit cellphone number
$this->Sms->carrier = 'Sprint'; //carrier string
$this->Sms->from = '5553331111'; //10 digit cellphone number OR email address
$this->Sms->text = 'This is a text message'; //Body of text message.
$this->Sms->send(); //Actually send the text message.
```

Or you can pass in these properties as an options array.

```
$this->Sms->send(array(
  'number' => '5551234567', //10 digit cellphone number
  'carrier' => 'Sprint', //carrier string
  'text' => 'This is a text', //Body of the text message
  'from' => '5553331111' //10 digit cellphone number OR email address
));
```

Comment: will it send sms even not providing username and password.

Comment: what is Sms? is it component?

Comment: This should be implemented as a CakeEmail adapter class (transport) IMHO.

Comment: where is the sms component found?

Comment: I have found it in http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/webtechnick/2009/11/07/sms-component but it shows  ".. messageID() on a non-object " error

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help with the implementation in CakePHP, but you should first think about how this SMS message is sent. There are a myriad of methods to accomplish the task of sending a SMS through a web application. The easiest is probably using an E-Mail to SMS gateway, but there are others including an SMS gateway provider or a GSM modem.

Here is a simplified diagram showing the path which the message travels:

[image]

The E-Mail to SMS method is probably the simplest, but is provider dependent. [Here](http://www.venture-ware.com/kevin/?p=83) is a list of many email to SMS addresses. With these you can just send an email via PHP and the provider's gateway converts the message.

If you want to use Clickatell (which is a SMS Gateway), they have already a PHP example on their site [here](https://www.clickatell.com/apis-scripts/scripts/php/). The important part are the following lines:

```
$url = "$baseurl/http/auth?user=$user&password=$password&api_id=$api_id";
$ret = file($url);
```

and

```
$url = "$baseurl/http/sendmsg?session_id=$sess_id&to=$to&text=$text";
$ret = file($url);
```

This means you need to request the auth and sendmsg with GET parameters. Sorry taht I need to let you figure this part out.

[source](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php--net-17693)